# How to add details to an mp3 file online?

Tags: php, mp3

I have huge number of mp3 files in my hosting. (More than 10000) I need to add details such as Title, Album, Artist to the songs/delete existing details of a song, but in online itself. Because it will be quiet impossible to download all the songs, edit the information and upload the songs again.

Any possibility through PHP?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes PHP will do as you can use these [ID3 functions](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.id3.php) to do just that.

Look for `id3_get_tag` and `id3_set_tag`.

Comment: Is there any option to add/remove Album art thru it?

Comment: Not directly. If you want to work with album art, I suggest you look for an open-source ID3 reader/writer for PHP. Or if you're not on a shared hosting, you can install binary tool to do it and call it from PHP with `exec()`

Comment: If you just want to remove album art with the PECL ID3 functions, you can try to [get the tag](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.id3-get-tag.php), then [remove the ID3 version 2 tag](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.id3-remove-tag.php) (which includes the album art), and [write back a simple ID3 version 1 tag](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.id3-set-tag.php) with the info you got.

Answer (score 1):

ID3v2 is trivial to manipulate, since it's just 128 bytes at the end of the file. ID3v1 is an arbitrary number of bytes at the FRONT of the file. Adding ID3v2 to a file that doesn't already have it, or increasing the amount of data in an existing ID3v2 tag will require recopying the entire file. Unless you have direct file-system level access to those files (e.g. via non-url fopen/fwrite/etc...), you WILL have to download the entire file, add the id3, then upload the modified version.